# Add table to Database

Tags: c#

I create simple table with one column, add it to new DataDatable, add new table to DataSet and try add new table to datase using SqlDataAdapter. No new added table in database when I check SqlServer.

```js
DataColumn new_table_primary_col = new DataColumn("Test_ID", typeof(int));
new_table_primary_col.AutoIncrement = true;
new_table_primary_col.AutoIncrementSeed = 1;
new_table_primary_col.AutoIncrementStep = 1;
DataTable new_table = new DataTable("MyTable");
new_table.Columns.Add(new_table_primary_col);

my_dataset.Tables.Add(new_table);
sql_data_adapter.Update(my_dataset);
```

Comment: Creating a table in C# code is not the same as creating it in your database. You'll need to write some explicit SQL and execute it using the data connection if you'd like to add the table from your C# code.

Comment: SQL data adapter updates the values in the database by executing the respective INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE statements for each inserted, updated, or deleted row in the DataSet. It doesn't allow for schema chnages

Comment: I don't see *any* database-related code. This is code that creates a DataTable, an *in-memory construct*. I think you need to start with a tutorial on ADO.NET and databases